# FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function setDoc() called with invalid data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, node-red

I am using `Firebase SDK's` within Node-red (as specified in [NPM docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) they can be used for IoT devices with NODE.js).

- I can use all of the CRUD methods with `Firebase RealtimeDatabase`.
- With `Firebase Firestore` I can only use `READ` and `DELETE` functionality.
- `SET` and `UPDATE` results in weird errors that I couldn't find answers
  anywhere on the internet.

I am importing `Firebase SDK's` through `require()` inside `settiings.js` and `functionGlobalContext` so I can access them in Node-red functions:

```
functionGlobalContext: {
    firebase: require('firebase/app'),
    firebaseDatabase: require('firebase/database'),
    firebaseFirestore: require('firebase/firestore'),
    // os:require('os'),
    // jfive:require("johnny-five"),
    // j5board:require("johnny-five").Board({repl:false})
},
```

First I initialize my whole Firebase project with this code (and everything initializes fine without errors):

```
//Load data from Global contexta
const firebase = global.get('firebase');
const firebaseDatabase = global.get('firebaseDatabase');
const firebaseFirestore = global.get('firebaseFirestore');


const firebaseConfig = {
     //my Firebase credentials
};

//Set up Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = firebaseDatabase.getDatabase();
const firestore = firebaseFirestore.getFirestore();

//Save the database reference to Global context
global.set('app', app);
global.set('database', database);
global.set('firestore', firestore);
```

And here I am trying basic `SET` operation with Firestore:

```
const ft = global.get('firebaseFirestore');
const firestore = global.get('firestore');

const frankDocRef = ft.doc(firestore, "users", "frank");
await ft.setDoc(frankDocRef, {
    name: "Frank",
    age: 12
});
```

Unfortunately even though this code is `ctrl+c` `ctrl+v` from Firestore docs I get this error:

```
"FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: a custom Object object (found in document users/frank)"
```

- When I use the same code inside a web app everything works fine.
- There has to be something going on under the hood with Node-red
- I tried creating the object using various methods and all of them resulted in the same error.

Does anybody have any idea what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Where is you code executed? On a node.js server? Or in a web app?

Comment: Hi, I see that you have asked the same question on [Node-red forum](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/node-red-is-somehow-mutating-normal-object-so-i-cant-pass-it-into-firestore-setdoc-function/53893) as well, and there are 2 answers present, did they help you??

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec my code is executed inside a Node-red environment which is build upon `NODE.js` if I am correct. Meaning it is not a `web app` but a NODE.js app running on Raspberry PI. But honestly I am not sure myself. Why? Can I make any changes to my code?

Comment: @Zeenath S N yes I saw those two answers. They suggested to use the `@google-cloud/firestore` and use Firestore in Google Cloud project (which is harder to setup but like a workaround it could work). But the answers didn't `answered` how to make the native JS SDK's working (because they ran into exactly same problems as I did in my environment).

Comment: Which version of the JS SDK are you using?

Comment: My JS SDK version is `9.1.3`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Do you have any other ideas what could be going under the hood?